# Take a patch of working directory changes in git

Tags: git, patch

How to take a patch of working directory changes in git directory. I know the method for taking the patch in SVN, but in git i don't know how to take it. pls help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `git diff` generates a patch that can be applied with most `patch` tools with a bit of tweaking (e.g. using `--strip`). Of course, `git apply`, if available, would be the preferred tool to apply such a patch.

Comment: but I want to create a .patch file for that. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: @AneeshNarayanan: Just redirect the output, e.g. `git diff >changes.patch`.